# Applying a recursive function or variable-length loop in to elements of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a function of the form:

```py
def f(x):

    n = 0

    while x > basecase:
        x = g(x)
        n += 1

    return n
```

Basically, it applies function `g()` on `x` until a condition is met, and then returns how many applications `n` it took.

I'd like to be able to call this function on numpy arrays, so I can graph `f(x)` for a large range of `x` with MatPlotLib. But as the function is now, that doesn't work -- the comparison between `x` (an array) and `basecase` (a scalar) is a problem, as is the fact that n is a single integer and not an array.

I know I could just call `vectorize`, but that's slow -- basically the same as iterating manually. What can I do here? Are there any functional-programming numpy functions that can save me here, or would I have to rewrite things with `nditer` if I wanted to avoid the overhead of `vectorize`?

Comment: You can rewrite f() and g() using Cython; in any case, you will need to add additional condition to prevent infinity looping. Note: the iterative process you are applying to g(x) is finding root of equation `x = g(x)`.  This iterative process will not converge in some cases (this depends on g(x)).

Comment: `nditer` is useful only as a stepping stone toward its use in `cython`.  If you must iterate (as opposed to using whole-array numpy operations), work with lists.

Comment: If `x` is an array, what would a `while x>basecase` mean?  All values of `x` greater than the target?  Any values greater?  `while` is a scalar operation, yes/no.  You need to be clear, more to yourself than us, what should happen.

Comment: @bubble `g(x)` is known, and the process is guaranteed to converge. I just didn't want to include it for sake of simplicity.
@hpaulj My goal is for the function to act exactly as if you fed it each element individually, so it tests each element separately and if the test fails, it loops. I'm not sure if something like that is possible (because you would kind of have to interleave python and C loops), which is why I'm asking.

Comment: So you aren't solving an array function, but rather a set of independent values. In other words, solving `g` for a bunch of different starting values.

Comment: Correct, I suppose. I'd like to be to feed it np arrays though, for convenience and ideally for speed.